# mysql query giving an error

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * 
   FROM rss_cron_data 
  WHERE 
    ((title LIKE '%sp100%' OR description LIKE '%sp100%')
    (title LIKE '%DEX%' OR description LIKE '%DEX%')
    (title LIKE '%NET%' OR description LIKE '%NET%')) 
    AND `pubDate` BETWEEN '2015-03-07 11:35:53' and '2015-03-14 11:35:53' 
ORDER BY `pubDate` desc
```

this is mysql query and its giving error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(title LIKE '%DEX%' OR description LIKE '%DEX%')(title LIKE
>   '%NET%' OR descripti' at line 3

whats wrong in this query can anyone explain please... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use and or between your conditions

```
SELECT * FROM (`rss_cron_data`) WHERE 
    ((title LIKE '%sp100%' OR description LIKE '%sp100%')
    (title LIKE '%DEX%' OR description LIKE '%DEX%')
    (title LIKE '%NET%' OR description LIKE '%NET%')) 
    AND `pubDate` BETWEEN '2015-03-07 11:35:53' and '2015-03-14 11:35:53' 
ORDER BY `pubDate` desc
```

changed to

```
SELECT * FROM (`rss_cron_data`) WHERE 
    ((title LIKE '%sp100%' OR description LIKE '%sp100%') or 
    (title LIKE '%DEX%' OR description LIKE '%DEX%') or 
    (title LIKE '%NET%' OR description LIKE '%NET%')) 
    AND `pubDate` BETWEEN '2015-03-07 11:35:53' and '2015-03-14 11:35:53' 
ORDER BY `pubDate` desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing logical condition between two condition. Change your condition like

```
((title LIKE '%sp100%' OR description LIKE '%sp100%') AND 
(title LIKE '%DEX%'  OR description LIKE '%DEX%') AND
(title LIKE '%NET%'  OR description LIKE '%NET%'))
```